# Excel - selecting from dropdown in protected worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a worksheet that I need to protect cells but allow for the user to use the dropdown selections in a few different ranges. The ranges have a variable column number since more columns can be added.

When I manually protect a worksheet and select the appropriate options, all cells are locked but the user can still select from the dropdowns in the necessary cells. However, when I lock the worksheet using VBA (which is necessary for some of my macros to function), this functionality dissapears.

All I'm doing in VBA is

```
'variable declarations

ws1.Unprotect Password:="pw"
ws1.Cells.Locked = False

'lots of code here

ws1.Cells.Locked = True
ws1.Protect Password:="pw", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
AllowDeletingColumns:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True,_
AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
```

I've read that `AllowFiltering:=True` is what's supposed to allow for the dropdown selection in locked cells, but that doesn't seem to work here. Anyone know what the difference is between me manually locking and locking through vba?

Comment: proposals: Place the functions/data where you need the locked worksheet on another worksheet? Perhaps a Userform and a dropdown there does solve your issue?

Comment: Your VBA is locking all cells on the sheet, including the ones you'd like to be editable.  Why do that?

Comment: Is it not necessary to lock them again after unlocking them? Or is unprotecting the worksheet enough for the code in the middle to do things like hide rows/add rows & columns/and add formulas?

Comment: And I won't be able to split the worksheet, the other columns (locked) columns and rows need to be next to the cells with drop-down selections for ease of use.

Comment: @TimWilliams Currently if I drop the `ws1.Cells.Locked = True`, after executing none of the cells are locked. This is if I manually set the worksheet protection, and then have the code just say `ws1.Unprotect Password :="pw"` .....code...`ws1.Protect Password:="pw"`

Comment: Locking/unlocking cells has no effect if the sheet is not protected.  You only have to unprotect the sheet to make changes - you don't need to touch the lock status of cells unless you want to change which cells can be edited once the sheet is re-protected.

Comment: Ah I totally misunderstood that then, that's great to know. Really simplifies what I'm trying to do then.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just specify the cell range that you want to let a user edit:

```
Range("Enter range here").Locked = False
```

I'm not sure without being able to test however the below should do the trick:

```
'variable declarations

ws1.Unprotect Password:="pw"
ws1.Cells.Locked = False

'lots of code here

ws1.Cells.Locked = True
Range("Enter range here").Locked = False 

ws1.Protect Password:="pw", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
AllowDeletingColumns:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True,_
AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
```

Comment: Yeah I think I'll need to do something like this, the issue is the range isn't static (columns can be added that would  also need to be locked) and I had a hard time looping through and locking appropriately.

Comment: Hmm that could be a bit tricky if they aren't static. Are you able to send the workbook over for me to see? If columns are being added, can you make sure your range or unlocked cells is formatted as a table and in the unlock vba for the editable range just target the table instead of a fixed range. I always find its better to work with named ranges/tables as opposed to fixed cell references as that can then accommodate moving your data around or an expanding table etc